# Font in Adobe XD

Tags: fonts, adobe, webfonts, adobe-xd

I tried downloading the font package from the apple website. But it is in pkg file format and cannot be added in Adobe XD. I tried extracting the pkg files option too but it is not working. How can I import fonts to Adobe XD?

Answer (score 0):

**Install fonts**

On your Mac, do one of the following:

- In the Font Book app toolbar, click the Add button , find and select a font, and then click Open.
- Drag the font archive to the icon for the Fonts app in the Dock.
- Double-click the font archive in the Finder, then click Install Font in the dialog that appears.

When you install a font, Scriptbook automatically checks or examines the font for errors.

**Scriptbook**

System fonts you can download are unclear in the list of fonts in the Font Book window.

- In the Scriptures app on your Mac, click All Scriptures in the table of contents.
- If you cannot see the table of contents, select Overview > Show Table of Contents.
- Choose an obscure font family or one or more obscure formats.
- Click Get at the top of the preview window, then click Get in the dialog that appears.

You can also look at [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201749) page from Apple as well as [this](https://support.apple.com/da-dk/guide/font-book/fntbk1000/mac) one.